# How do you populate a multi-value field with a specific number of empty fields?

Tags: entities

How would you go about generating a specific number of empty fields inside of a multi-value field on page load? In my case this multi-value field is a simple text field, and I'll be passing a URL param to the form page with the number of empty fields it should display.